# Getting name of a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, npm, fs

Does anyone know how to get the name of a module in node.js / javascript

so lets say you do

```
var RandomModule = require ("fs")
.
.
.
console.log (RandomModule.name)
// -> "fs"
```

Comment: It is possible, but not that way. Wait a minute I'm building an example.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to trace your dependencies, you can try using require hooks.

Create a file called `myRequireHook.js`

```
var Module = require('module');
var originalRequire = Module.prototype.require;
Module.prototype.require = function(path) {
    console.log('*** Importing lib ' + path + ' from module ' + this.filename);
    return originalRequire(path);
};
```

This code will hook every `require` call and log it into your console.

Not exactly what you asked first, but maybe it helps you better.

And you need to call just once in your main .js file (the one you start with `node main.js`).

So in your `main.js`, you just do that:

```
require('./myRequireHook');
var fs = require('fs');
var myOtherModule = require('./myOtherModule');
```

It will trace `require` in your other modules as well.

This is the way transpilers like [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/) work. They hook every `require` call and transform your code before load.

Comment: Interesting ! I will try it out ! Thanks a lot for your help. 

This is the module I am trying to write: 

https://github.com/JoyKrishnaMondal/GetRidOfError

Basically I want to log to the user which module is causing them errors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would need that, but there is a way.

The `module` variable, which is loaded automatically in every node.js file, contains an array called `children`. This array contains every child module loaded by `require` in your current file.

This way, you need to strict compare your loaded reference with the cached object version in this array in order to discover which element of the array corresponds to your module.

Look this sample:

```
var pieces = require('../src/routes/headers');

var childModuleId = discoverChildModuleId(pieces, module);
console.log(childModuleId);

function discoverChildModuleId(object, moduleObj) {
    "use strict";
    var childModule = moduleObj.children.find(function(child) {
        return object === child.exports;
    });
    return childModule && childModule.id;
}
```

This code will find the correspondence in `children` object and bring its id.

I put `module` as a parameter of my function so you can export it to a file. Otherwise, it would show you modules of where `discoverChildModule` function resides (if it is in the same file won't make any difference, but if exported it will).

Notes:

- Module ids have the full path name. So don't expect finding `../src/routes/headers`. You will find something like: `/Users/david/git/...`
- My algorithm won't detect exported attributes like `var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema`. It is possible to make a function which is capable of this, but it will suffer many issues.

Comment: yes ! thanks for that information ! 

I am writing a tiny module for managing your modules, so that is why I need it.

Comment: The problem with your solution is it does not work with native modules like fs :(

Comment: Unfortunately not, because they don't have a source to be loaded by `require` (they are native compiled into Node.js engine).

Answer (score 0):

From within a module (doesn't work at the REPL) you can...

```
console.log( global.process.mainModule.filename );
```

And you'll get '/home/ubuntu/workspace/src/admin.js'